# Show the table name in database regarding the model in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, database, django-models

I have to find the database table name of resoective model in my project, how can i do it .  I previously tried the

```py
 class Meta:
        db_table = 'tablenameIWant'
```

but how can I see the table name ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Meta class of models can be accessed with the *_meta* attribute.
So:

```
MyModel._meta.db_table
```